# Finding shortest possible substring that contains a String

Tags: java, string, algorithm

This was a question asked in a recent programming interview.

Given a random string S and another string T with unique elements, find the minimum consecutive sub-string of S such that it contains all the elements in T. 
Say,

```
S='adobecodebanc' 
T='abc' 
Answer='banc'
```

I've come up with a solution,

```
public static String completeSubstring(String T, String S){

        String minSub = T;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <T.length()-1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= T.length() ; j++) {
                String sub = T.substring(i,j);
                if(stringContains(sub, S)){
                    if(sub.length() < minSub.length()) minSub = sub;
                }
            }
        }
        return minSub;

    }
    private static boolean stringContains(String t, String s){
        //if(t.length() <= s.length()) return false;

        int[] arr = new int[256];

        for (int i = 0; i <t.length() ; i++) {
            char c = t.charAt(i);
            arr[c -'a'] = 1;
        }
        boolean found = true;
        for (int i = 0; i <s.length() ; i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if(arr[c - 'a'] != 1){
                found = false;
                break;
            }else continue;
        }
        return found;
    }
```

This algorithm has a O(n3) complexity, which but naturally isn't great. Can someone suggest a better algorithm.

Comment: Is there a typo in the sample? `band` doesn't appear to be a consecutive sub-string of S at all ...

Comment: Yup, you can do this in O(N) time.  This is a good interview question, though -- I'd hate to ruin it.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Can you show us how? I agree you're probably right.

Comment: @yaccob I don't understand what you're talking about. Where did you find `band`

Comment: @MattTimmermans I tried a sliding window algorithm a modified Kadane, but I don't that can guarantee the answer will be the shortest substring. It will be a substring.

Comment: @Zeus Originally you said the answer was band. Maljam corrected it.

Comment: @PaulBoddington OK O(N) solution added.  I suppose it's pretty unlikely that someone will happen to read it before going to an interview.

Comment: @Zeus band was there before it was corrected. In the meantime it's fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the O(N) solution.

The important thing to note re: complexity is that each unit of work involves incrementing either `start` or `end`, they don't decrease, and the algorithm stops before they both get to the end.

```
public static String findSubString(String s, String t)
{
    //algorithm moves a sliding "current substring" through s
    //in this map, we keep track of the number of occurrences of
    //each target character there are in the current substring

    Map<Character,int[]> counts = new HashMap<>();
    for (char c : t.toCharArray())
    {
        counts.put(c,new int[1]);
    }

    //how many target characters are missing from the current substring
    //current substring is initially empty, so all of them
    int missing = counts.size();

    //don't waste my time
    if (missing<1)
    {
        return "";
    }

    //best substring found
    int bestStart = -1, bestEnd = -1;

    //current substring
    int start=0, end=0;
    while (end<s.length())
    {
        //expand the current substring at the end
        int[] cnt = counts.get(s.charAt(end++));
        if (cnt!=null)
        {
            if (cnt[0]==0)
            {
                --missing;
            }
            cnt[0]+=1;
        }
        //while the current substring is valid, remove characters
        //at the start to see if a shorter substring that ends at the
        //same place is also valid 
        while(start<end && missing<=0)
        {
            //current substring is valid
            if (end-start < bestEnd-bestStart || bestEnd<0)
            {
                bestStart = start;
                bestEnd = end;
            }
            cnt = counts.get(s.charAt(start++));
            if (cnt != null)
            {
                cnt[0]-=1;
                if (cnt[0]==0)
                {
                    ++missing;
                }
            }
        }
        //current substring is no longer valid.  we'll add characters
        //at the end until we get another valid one
        //note that we don't need to add back any start character that
        //we just removed, since we already tried the shortest valid string
        //that starts at start-1

    }
    return(bestStart<=bestEnd ? s.substring(bestStart,bestEnd) : null);
}
```

Comment: At the cost of sounding naive, could you comment your code a bit with a few lines of the logic, I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: @Zeus, sure.  Do these help?

Comment: Great answer (+1).

Answer (score 1):

I know that there already is an adequate O(N) complexity answer, but I tried to figure it out on my own without looking it up, just because it's a fun problem to solve and thought I would share. Here's the O(N) solution that I came up with:

```
public static String completeSubstring(String S, String T){
    int min = S.length()+1, index1 = -1, index2 = -1;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> index = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 
    HashSet<Character> targetChars = new HashSet<Character>();
    for(char c : T.toCharArray()) targetChars.add(c);

    //reduce initial sequence to only target chars and keep track of index
    //Note that the resultant string does not allow the same char to be consecutive

    StringBuilder filterS = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0, s = 0 ; i < S.length() ; i++) {
        char c = S.charAt(i);
        if(targetChars.contains(c)) {
            if(s > 0 && filterS.charAt(s-1) == c) {
                index.get(s-1).add(i);
            } else {
                filterS.append(c);
                index.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
                index.get(s).add(i);
                s++;
            }
        }
    }

    //Not necessary to use regex, loops are fine, but for readability sake
    String regex = "([abc])((?!\\1)[abc])((?!\\1)(?!\\2)[abc])";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(filterS.toString());

    for(int i = 0, start = -1, p1, p2, tempMin, charSize = targetChars.size() ; m.find(i) ; i = start+1) {
        start = m.start();
        ArrayList<Integer> first = index.get(start);
        p1 = first.get(first.size()-1);
        p2 = index.get(start+charSize-1).get(0);
        tempMin = p2-p1;

        if(tempMin < min) {
            min = tempMin;
            index1 = p1;
            index2 = p2;
        }
    }

    return S.substring(index1, index2+1);   
}
```

I'm pretty sure the complexity is O(N), please correct if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Alternative implementation of O(N) algorithm proposed by [@MattTimmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5483526/matt-timmermans), which uses `Map<Integer, Integer>` to count occurrences and `Set<Integer>` to store chars from T that are present in current substring:

```
public static String completeSubstring(String s, String t) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> occ 
        = t.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c, c -> 0));

    Set<Integer> found = new HashSet<>();      // characters from T found in current match
    int start = 0;                             // current match
    int bestStart = Integer.MIN_VALUE, bestEnd = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int ci = s.charAt(i);                  // current char
        if (!occ.containsKey(ci))              // not from T
            continue;
        occ.put(ci, occ.get(ci) + 1);          // add occurrence
        found.add(ci);
        for (int j = start; j < i; j++) {      // try to reduce current match
            int cj = s.charAt(j);
            Integer c = occ.get(cj);
            if (c != null) { 
                if (c == 1) {                  // cannot reduce anymore
                    start = j;
                    break;
                } else 
                    occ.put(cj, c - 1);        // remove occurrence
            }
        }
        if (found.size() == occ.size()         // all chars found
            && (i - start < bestEnd - bestStart)) {
            bestStart = start;
            bestEnd = i;
        }
    }
    return bestStart < 0 ? null : s.substring(bestStart, bestEnd + 1); 
}
```

Comment: Could you comment a bit of the Java8 syntax that you're using.

Comment: well, it's just for putting `0` values to keys that are chars in T. `t.chars()` returns stream of `int` (each `int` represent a `char` in T), `.boxed()` converts it to stream of `Integer`, and two arguments in `.toMap()` are functions, the first one maps item to key (`c -> c` means "return item itself"), the second maps item to value (so `c -> 0` means "return 0 for any item").